# Count the number of matching elements in two arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm working on a homework assignment for Comp Sci I, and I've tried literally everything I could find on the internet and in my textbook in an attempt to count the number of matching elements in two C++ arrays. I simply can't find a way to make my code count the number of matching elements in two arrays of the same size (same value, same position). For instance, if array1 has 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, and array2 has 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, there is one matching element, the 3. How can I get my code to perform this seemingly simple task?

Couldn't find an answer anywhere. My textbook only shows how to see if the arrays match exactly without counting the number of matches, and I haven't been able to find anyone else with this exact question for C++.

Here's my function so far:

```
int matchCounter(int lottery[5], int user[5], int matches, int SIZE)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (count < SIZE; count++;)
    {
        if (lottery[count] == user[count])
        {
            matches++;
        }
}

    return matches;
} // end matchCounter
```

SIZE is a constant that equals 5, by the way. It would seem that this should work, but every time I run the program, it displays 0 matches, even in there are some matches. If anyone could help me out, I would be forever in your debt. Seriously, there's got to be some incredibly simple thing I'm just not seeing. Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: [std::set_intersection](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/)

Comment: Also, the code in the question doesn't compile

Comment: I'm pretty sure you haven't tried "literally everything."

Comment: you should remove the 'class' and 'homework' tags from this question.  The 'class' tag refers to the programming construct, not to a class at school/university.  The 'homework' tag is obsolete and in the process of being removed see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` statement is garbled. Try this:

```
int matchCounter(int lottery[5], int user[5], int matches, int SIZE)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
    {
...
```

For reason why your program always fails: `count++` is put in the position of the condition in the `for` loop, so every time this `for` loop is executed, `count` is evaluated and considered to be the condition, and then `count` is incremented by 1. However, every time `count` starts from 0 (as in `int count = 0;`), so the `for` loop actually never gets executed, and `matches` remain zero.

**EDIT:**

From your source code, you're not using your return value, which is also suggested by @jimhark. Change the function signature to:

```
int matchCounter(int lottery[5], int user[5], int SIZE)
```

And call with:

```
matches = matchCounter(lottery, user, 5);
```

Otherwise, your return value of the function `matchCounter` is ignored, while `int matches` only plays the role of a local variable in the function.

Read this about why the `matches` doesn't work: http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/CS2213/swap/swap.html (in a similar setting)

Comment: Still doesn't work, even in the format you listed. Perhaps there is a problem somewhere else in my code.

Here is a link to my source code:

[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pe4xuwj1qwkgivc/Assignment%206.cpp)

Comment: @user1840483 Change Line 50 to `matches = matchCounter(lottery, user, matches, SIZE);`

Comment: @user1840483 If you think this is ok, please accept it as the answer by clicking the check mark on the left. Thx. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your may not be using your return value. Change sig to:

```
int matchCounter(int lottery[5], int user[5], int SIZE)
{
    matches = 0;
```

And make sure your're calling with:

```
matches = matchCounter(lottery, user, 5);
```

If you need a running sum, use:

```
matches += matchCounter(lottery, user, 5);
```

In any case matchCounter doesn't care what running total is, so why pass it in?

Also you may need to sort the lists first.

Comment: The down vote is a little harsh. He says he's always printing 0 and doesn't show how the function is called. This was worth checking.

Comment: @XiaoJia, thanks for that. I think whoever down voted has probably been programming so long they don't remember what it's like learning C. Almost everyone makes mistakes like this at the beginning. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework, I will try to point the errors without giving the solution.

The form of a for loop is:

```
for (INIT; COND; STEP) {
    BODY;
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
INIT;
while (COND) {
    BODY;
    STEP;
}
```

The way you did, your INIT is `count < SIZE`, which doesn't do anything. Your "COND" is `count++`, which returns 0 on the first iteration. As you may know, 0 is false, in the context of a boolean. Therefore, your for loop body is not being executed at all.

Also, you should not pass `matches` as an argument. It should be a local variable initialized with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
int matches=0;

for(int i=0;i<ARRAY.SIZE;i++) {
   for(int j=0;j<ARRAY.SIZE;j++) {
       if(arr1[i]==arr2[j]) {
          matches++;
          arr2[j]=NULL;
       }
   }
}
```